# In simplifying the formula that I've derived for finding the square root of a complex number to the standard formula.

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

So by easy means, I derived

$\sqrt{a+ib} = \sqrt{\frac{a(a+1)+b^2}{2}}+i(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a(a+1)+b^2}})$

But then I checked for the actual formula it is this;

$\sqrt{a+ib} = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}+a}{2}}± i(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}-a}{2}})$

So how do you simplify that to this?
Btw here is the derivation;

> Let $\sqrt{a+ib} = x+iy$
>
> $a+ib=x^2 - y^2 + i2xy$
>
> We know, $(x^2-y^2)^2 + (2xy)^2 = x^2 + y^2$
>
> or, $x^2 + y^2 = a^2 + b^2$
>
> Hence we get $x = \sqrt{\frac{a+a^2+b^2}{2}}$ and
>   $y=\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+a+b^2}}$
>
> Therefore;
>
> $\sqrt{a+ib} =
> > \sqrt{\frac{a(a+1)+b^2}{2}}+i(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a(a+1)+b^2}})$

Comment: Consider $a=4, x=2, b=y=0.$  Then $\sqrt{a+ib}=x$ but $x^2+y^2\ne a^2+b^2$

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in your derivation.  You should have $(x^2+y^2)^\color{red}2=a^2+b^2$.

This follows from $a=x^2-y^2$ and $b=2xy$ (or from known properties of complex modulus).

Thus, $a=x^2-\dfrac {b^2}{4x^2}$;

solving this quadratic equation in $x^2$ yields $x^2=\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2$ as the correct answer.

Comment: And you can find $y$ fairly easily from $y^2=x^2-a$

Answer (score -1):

One of the approache is use Euler form if Z is a complex numbers such that $ Z\, = \,r.e^{ix}$ then 
Square root of Z will be $Z_{1}= \, \sqrt{r} . e^{iy} $ 
Where angle y will be x/2 and (x + 2π)/2.